# Make a wordpress post loop add a dynamic custom style class based on order

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a need to include an extra style on my post loop so i end up with extra styling options, like this:

```
<article class="first-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="second-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="third-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="first-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="second-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
<article class="third-column format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
```

And then it repeats this order. It's so i can have my posts three wide and style them nicely.

The key one i wish to add is first-column, second column, and so on.

Any help on what to add in wordpress for this?

This is what currently creates this loop:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside your loop :

```
$classes = array(
    0=>'first-column',
    1=>'second-column',
    2=>'third-column'
);
$i = 0;
```

In your loop :

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($classes[$i++%3]); ?>>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's only putting "first column" for all of them with the above code, though.

Comment: Make sure `$classes` and `$i` are declared outside the loop (before `if(have_posts()) while(have_posts()): the_post();`)

Comment: Thankyou - I had an issue where some of the loop was being called from another template, so the first part of the code was in one file, and the rest was in another, it didn't work like this?

Comment: Not sure how it can work like that, add `global $classes; global $i;` in the beginning of each files you use.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks worked for me very well...

I used it on a bootstrap theme i develop currently and i wanted two backgrounds colors. One lighter and one darker for each post. So it is easier to identify each new post. Worked fine I just used

```
$classes = array(
    0=>'light-bg',
    1=>'darl-bg'
);
$i = 0;
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($classes[$i++%2]); ?>>
// The rest of your post html goes here
</div>
```